# how to force thin to use the rails logger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, thin

By default `thin` logs in a separate file (something like `thin.0.log`). This makes debugging hard since exceptions will be logged in thin.0.log while all the other information is in the Rails log. How can you force thin to log in the same file as Rails?

Answer (score 0):

As annoying as it may be, that data is meant to be separated from the `development.log` or `production.log` (which is what I assume you're referring to). Thin logs handle everything related directly to the thin server as far as reasons why it can't start up, saying that it did, what port it's bound to, etc. The other logs are for your application itself, such as exceptions, page renders, requests, etc...

You'll be glad for this when you run into an issue with thin not starting due to a syntax error in a model or something. It's nicer to have one clean log for those instances, rather than filtering through thousands of lines of `served static asset...`

Rails is all about everything being organized and having its own place.

Comment: I start thin as a rack-adapter and right now exceptions are logged in `thin.0.log`, whereas my `test.log` contains information about the request and 500-status (no stack-trace). That's hard to piece together.